# How to Get the count of rows inserted with single statement using triggers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, insert, count

is that possible?

clear info abt the question is - i am inserting data from excel using one insert statement - multiple statement inserting at a time. but as of my idea trigger raises only for one statement at a time.

is that count is possible means please give me a suggestion on this issue.

Thanks In Advance
Devendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the trigger- no its not possible if you insert data row by row. 
You could probably make some workarounds, for example, you can do insert in some temporary table and then insert all records from there in the real table by using

```
Insert Into Table (...)
Select (...) From #tempTable
```

But its better if you count inserted records at excel side..

Comment: @Janis - ok i understood but i need to do some changes to insert in another table - another table have different fields